# how to take any constructor type and convert it to a function type which accepts the same arguments?

Tags: typescript, arguments

Consider the code below, I created a class that has a constructor that receives an argument with a generic type, which is used to define the type of the parameter received by the second argument, in the case below the a parameter of the callback function is MouseEvent, because the value of the first parameter:

```js
class MyClass<T extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>{
    constructor(tagName: T, lister: (ev: HTMLElementEventMap[T]) => any) { }
}

new MyClass("click", ev => { })
//                   ^^ (parameter) ev: MouseEvent
```

however, if I create a function whose rest argument is of type ConstructorParameters<typeof MyClass>, the second parameter instead resolve MouseEvent type for the callback parameter, is resolved `Event | UIEvent | AnimationEvent | MouseEvent | FocusEvent | DragEvent | ErrorEvent | PointerEvent | ... 6 more ... | ClipboardEvent`

```js
function myFunction(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof MyClass>) {}

myFunction("click", ev => { })
//                  ^^ (parameter) ev: Event | UIEvent | AnimationEvent | MouseEvent | FocusEvent | DragEvent | ErrorEvent | PointerEvent | ... 6 more ... | ClipboardEvent
```

How can I get the correct type for the callback parameter without rewriting the types for the `myFunction` function?

is it possible?

Comment: Ehhh, there's no higher-order type operations that will do this purely at the type level.  You can sort of get what you want by some minor abuse of [higher order inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/DmMqrm)... does that work for you?  If so I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Woow! is this magic? I didn't really understand how it works, but it works, can you explain it better?

Comment: I noticed that this generates JS codes, this approach is not only in the field of 'types', can you say why this is and if there is any solution that does not generate even more JS codes?

Comment: As I said, I do not know of any solution that works purely at the type level.  It would propbably require higher-kinded types of the sort requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), but those are not part of the language.

Comment: thanks for the help, please make an answer so i can mark it as useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to say "take any constructor type and convert it to a *function* type which accepts the same arguments".

---

One problem is that TypeScript's type system doesn't have a good way to express "the arguments of a callable or constructable thing" which works for *generic* functions.  If you have a function like

```
function foo<T>(x: T, y: T): void { }
```

and try to get its parameter list, the generic parameter `T` will be replaced with its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints).  In this instance, `T` is unconstrained, and therefore has an implicit constraint of `unknown`:

```
type FooParams = Parameters<typeof foo>;
// type FooParams = [x: unknown, y: unknown]
```

TypeScript does not have the right sort of generic types to represent the parameter list of a generic function.  A generic function has its generic type parameters on the call signature.  But a tuple type like `[x: unknown, y: unknown]` has no call signature and cannot take a generic type parameter:

```
// Not valid TS, do not use this:
type FooParams = <T>[x: T, y: T];
```

In order to represent this, TypeScript would need something like arbitrary *generic value types*, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#17574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574)... but it doesn't have these.

---

Okay, so instead of worrying about a tuple type, maybe we could automatically transform one generic function type into another.  Unfortunately, again, the language doesn't have the right sort of type operators to do this.  In order to capture the relationship between a generic function and its type parameter, TypeScript would probably need something like "higher kinded types", as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)... but it doesn't have these either.

---

Before TypeScript 3.4, I'd say we would be completely stuck.  But Typescript 3.4 introduced support for [higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions).  This is a partial implementation of  higher kinded types, but there's no type-level syntax available to use it.  You can transform an actual generic function *value* into another generic function *value*, where the type of the output function is related to the type of the input function exactly as you want.  If you don't have an actual function value, then you can make one or pretend to make one, do the higher order inference on that value, and then get the type of the output function.  But this, as you noted, is adding some actual JavaScript to your output that you don't need at all, if all you care about is the typing.  For the `MyClass` example, it looks like this:

```
// abuse TS3.4 support for higher order inference from generic functions
const ctorArgs = <A extends any[], R>(f: new (...a: A) => R): (...a: A) => void => null!
const myFunc = ctorArgs(MyClass)
type MyFunctionType = typeof myFunc;

const myFunction: MyFunctionType = (...args) => {}
myFunction("click", ev => { ev.buttons })
```

You can see that `ctorArgs` is doing the type manipulation you want, but at the value level.  In the above code, `ctorArgs` is throwing away its input and just pretending to return a function; and we are in turn throwing away the output and just getting its type.

Since you can't escape the JavaScript part of this, maybe you can actually use it tow your advantage and implement `myFunction` generically.  What would you be doing that would take a constructor and turning it into a void-returning function?  Calling `new` on it and then throwing away the result?  Like this:

```
const makeMyFunction = <A extends any[], R>(
  f: new (...a: A) => R): (...a: A) => void =>
    (...a) => { new f(...a) } // whatever the implementation should do

const myFunction = makeMyFunction(MyClass);
```

In that case, `myFunction` comes out for free.  But the suitability of this depends on your use case, which I don't know.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8BpaBTAHgFywDsATGAay3gHsAzaACQBVYAZAURCwFsi82A3XrDAAHAHwBvAFDRZ0YFUIQ8AJwCuwPFRUAKPGADmAOTA8AXNHQAaaCACWyrCos6s-C01YduvAUNEA2ugAugCU0AC8YtBghPDhEtAAvlIpUgD06TEARmoQWNCMAMoAzAB0ACzQEGoiItp40DTa0AAWdgatTtDaxN12hDRORMAFNCpUXNAGRE52wE1qhJp2ihBSCkqNmtoAgioGMBHQqLvY+ESkMXEBwTYASmI6NBaEWADu0DplP2AWu+EotB7qEXD8yn9oADItF+FQ7MQYdBCGoQCAAIQbNaNLjwABiSwWxx2Kn2hx0CGQkAgoSkeHgIgKCAJyzwq0IjAZBWO9MZtGguJZwAA3FIsVsBfjCWzFBZmdL2ZzGZEvuCwAcaUjEilBQrFDoAESgeZkA02Nxa7D8Mq5PBaJTJWlSGh6whNKhUVCMJ44CyMGzwP2g6BwhHQbV0rnQPEegAK6tMR2g8ZUpiwBBUEFQvKw-OaVDEosy0Bz0bjCa4SYCvugSzIhCo70IAYsdYbTeCYuLRiojX4YHsiOKNmIVGRvdr+RL7XWxdLMaoKcTKq9YmrfpbhWCovFygFYAo8tZ7JXZ1wBBIMFi8FuDyeL2RH1Vv3+gOiILBL6hb5D8MRURkORvl+H9EjeT4aGAiFwjSTY911Y9FAAJhVLgDywI8Vn1SkUBpYUgA)